# Session["something"] giving problems in the database

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I will try to describe my problem as best as I can,

I'm doing a school project, where we have created a website and a database. This website you able to login to and then search, add and remove different products to or from some database tables. What it is and so on does not really matter.

The main part is: For example, you have a database table called Actual stock. And a product table containing products. Then you log in to the website, search for a product, and then add it to your Actual Stock table, with how many you want in quantity.

This is working just fine, but I run in to a little problem. Let me explain the problem:
If I first login to the site, search for a product and then add this product to my Actual stock, this will get added into the database, with no problems at all. But now, if another user logs in to the site, (while im still logged in) searches for the same product, and then adds one of them to his Actual stock, he will get two of them in quantity, (It takes the one I have on my list and adds it with the one he is adding) Same goes if he removes them from his Actual Stock, they will also be removed from my actual stock.

Hope you guys understands the description of the problem.

This is how I have made the login, so that the logged in user will get a session ID matching the user ID from the database:

```
 protected void btnlogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    SSDataContext db = new SSDataContext();

    var myUser = db.Userdbs.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Email == TUname.Text && x.Password == TPas.Text);

    if (myUser != null)
    {
        Session["userid"] = myUser.UserID.ToString();
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
```

And this is working fine, with only one user logged in.

This is how I add the given product to the database table:

```
 protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    SSDataContext db = new SSDataContext();
    ActualStock myAdd = new ActualStock();

    if (!db.ActualStocks.Any(u => u.EAN == addSoeg.Text))
    {
        myAdd.EAN = addSoeg.Text;           
        myAdd.UserID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["userid"]);
        myAdd.Quantity = 0;
        db.ActualStocks.InsertOnSubmit(myAdd);
        db.SubmitChanges();

    }
    myAdd = db.ActualStocks.Single(x => x.EAN == addSoeg.Text);
    myAdd.UserID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["userid"]);       
    myAdd.Quantity = myAdd.Quantity + Convert.ToInt32(quantity.Text);
    db.SubmitChanges();
    Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
}
```

This is also working just fine, again with only one user logged in to the site.

Can any one help me to understand why the session ID's get mixed up, and products get added and removed from

Hope I have explained my self enough, so that you are able to understand what's going on.

If you need more information on other stuff, please let me know.

We are using MSSQL database and coding in C# using LINQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should filter your records by userId:

```
 var userId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["userid"]);
 myAdd = db.ActualStocks.Single(x => x.EAN == addSoeg.Text&&x.UserId == userId);
```

**Update:**
You don't get actual stock of concrete user from db. Instead you always get single actual stock.

To resolve your issue, you should always get actual stock of current user. So you code should be:

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    SSDataContext db = new SSDataContext();
    ActualStock myAdd = new ActualStock();
    var userId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["userid"]);

    if (!db.ActualStocks.Any(u => u.EAN == addSoeg.Text&&u.UserId == userId))
    {
        myAdd.EAN = addSoeg.Text;           
        myAdd.UserID = userId;
        myAdd.Quantity = 0;
        db.ActualStocks.InsertOnSubmit(myAdd);
        db.SubmitChanges();

    }
    myAdd = db.ActualStocks.Single(x => x.EAN == addSoeg.Text&&x.UserId == userId);
    myAdd.UserID = userId ;       
    myAdd.Quantity = myAdd.Quantity + Convert.ToInt32(quantity.Text);
    db.SubmitChanges();
    Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, could you please explain to me why you want to do it this way, and what is wrong with the other method? As im still very new to coding and in a learning phase, i will benefit alot from a explanation. (And sorry for the english, its not my main language)

Comment: Typo in the first if statement.  you use `u` as your var, then switch to `x`.

Comment: It looks like this did the trick, all tho, i'm not sure why just yet. But i will look more into it, and then i'm sure i will understand it bettet. Thank you very much for your help. And explanation, really appreciate it.